# Kid travels back in time to either scotland or celtic

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in the early 2000's (2000-2003) at a high school library about a kid/young adult who traveled back in time to medieval Scotland and it had some kind of knot on the cover. It was more of an adventure/action book and not a romance title. Not 100% sure but it might have been part of a series of books. I do recall the book being fairly thick too.

Comment: Was the main character (time traveler) male or female? Can you remember any of the "adventures" that happened? Do you recall how the time travel happened?

Comment: I want to say that they where male, as for details I cannot recall, its been 15 years since I read it.

Comment: So, not Outlander?